# Internet explorer addon. How do I use postMessage in c#

Tags: c#, postmessage, bho, ieaddon

I have an internet explorer addon.
I have an event listener that I attach on document load:

```
private void attachOnChangeEvent(HTMLDocument doc, Boolean flag)
{ 
   IHTMLWindow3 rawWindow = (IHTMLWindow3)(webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument).parentWindow;
   rawWindow.attachEvent("onmessage", new HtmlHandler(onmessageWindow, (IHTMLWindow2)rawWindow));
    }

private void onmessageWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(typeof(sender).ToString());
}
```

The above works fine.

Now further on Im trying to post a message

```
HTMLWindow2 rawWindow = (HTMLWindow2)(webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument).parentWindow; 

rawWindow.postMessage(s, rawWindow.location.pathname);
```

But I keep on getting an exception.

How do I correcty call postMessage?

Heres the eventhandler code

```
using MSHTML;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Authenticator
{
    class HtmlHandler : IReflect
    {
        public HtmlHandler(EventHandler evHandler, IHTMLWindow2 sourceWindow)
        {
            this.eventHandler = evHandler;
            this.htmlWindow = sourceWindow;
        }

        public IHTMLWindow2 SourceHTMLWindow
        {
            get { return this.htmlWindow; }
        }

        #region IReflect

        FieldInfo IReflect.GetField(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return this.typeIReflectImplementation.GetField(name, bindingAttr);
        }

        FieldInfo[] IReflect.GetFields(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return this.typeIReflectImplementation.GetFields(bindingAttr);
        }

        MemberInfo[] IReflect.GetMember(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return this.typeIReflectImplementation.GetMember(name, bindingAttr);
        }

        MemberInfo[] IReflect.GetMembers(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return this.typeIReflectImplementation.GetMembers(bindingAttr);
        }

        MethodInfo IReflect.GetMethod(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return this.typeIReflectImplementation.GetMethod(name, bindingAttr);
        }

        MethodInfo IReflect.GetMethod(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
        {
            return this.typeIReflectImplementation.GetMethod(name, bindingAttr, binder, types, modifiers);
        }

        MethodInfo[] IReflect.GetMethods(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return this.typeIReflectImplementation.GetMethods(bindingAttr);
        }

        PropertyInfo[] IReflect.GetProperties(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return this.typeIReflectImplementation.GetProperties(bindingAttr);
        }

        PropertyInfo IReflect.GetProperty(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return this.typeIReflectImplementation.GetProperty(name, bindingAttr);
        }

        PropertyInfo IReflect.GetProperty(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
        {
            return this.typeIReflectImplementation.GetProperty(name, bindingAttr, binder, returnType, types, modifiers);
        }

        public object InvokeMember(string name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object target, object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, string[] namedParameters)
        {
            if (name == "[DISPID=0]")
            {
                if (this.eventHandler != null)
                {
                    this.eventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        Type IReflect.UnderlyingSystemType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.typeIReflectImplementation.UnderlyingSystemType;
            }
        }

        #endregion


        private IReflect typeIReflectImplementation = typeof(HtmlHandler);
        private EventHandler eventHandler;
        private IHTMLWindow2 htmlWindow;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: ok, what is the inner exception?

Comment: theres no inner exception